# Making a bill in Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to print bill but having problem in spacing due to different length of characters. In the below code I have added a length check so that if product name which is in this case index[0] have greater number of letters will get lesser space than others. But now I am having a problem in index[2] that is quantity. If I put same number of quantity for example (2 & 3) in both lists it works but when a quantity goes in tens or hunderds spacing error occurrs. for example (2 & 23)

```
tprice = 0
tup = [['apple','100','2'],['blackberry','100','23']]
f= open(filename,'w')
g= open('recpt.txt','r')
lines = g.readlines()
for line in lines:
    base = line.split()
    tup.append(base)
print('S.no','\t','Product','\t','Unit','\t','Price')
for i in range(len(tup)):
    if len(tup[i][0]) <= 7:
      print([i+1],'\t',tup[i][0],'\t','\t',tup[i][2],'\t',tup[i][1])
    else:
        print([i+1], '\t', tup[i][0], '\t', tup[i][2],'\t',tup[i][1])
    price = int(tup[i][1])
    tprice += price
print(tprice)
```

what should I do to make the bill equal

[image: Here is the screenshot of error]

Comment: Try out the tabulate library which is made for exactly this situation: https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate

Comment: Why don't you just store everything in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` function seems perfect for this. Try it like this:

```
tprice = 0
tup = [['apple', '100', '2'], ['blackberry', '100', '23']]
myformat = "{:<10}{:<25}{:<5}{}"

f = open(filename, 'w')
g = open('recpt.txt', 'r')
lines = g.readlines()

for line in lines:
    base = line.split()
    tup.append(base)

print(myformat.format('S.no', 'Product', 'Unit', 'Price'))

for i in range(len(tup)):
    if len(tup[i][0]) <= 7:
        print(myformat.format(str([i + 1]), tup[i][0], tup[i][2], tup[i][1]))
    else:
        print(myformat.format(str([i + 1]), tup[i][0], tup[i][2], tup[i][1]))

    price = int(tup[i][1])
    tprice += price

print(tprice)
```

Output:

```
S.no      Product                  Unit Price
[1]       apple                    2    100 
[2]       blackberry               23   100
```

Comment: There's no need to call `str()` on the arguments to `myformat.format()`.  The formatting takes care of the stringification.

Comment: Thanks. Removed all `str` casts except `str([i+1])`.